# Importing string as an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, string, import, ordereddictionary

I have a file with no extension with lines like this (ignore the spacing between the lines, but each line is a separate row):

```
OrderedDict([('key1', u'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])
OrderedDict([('key1', u'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])
OrderedDict([('key1', u'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])
```

when I import it to Python

```
snap_fh = open("C:\Users\.......")
for row in snap_fh:
    print(type(row))
```

rows are `"strings"` and I cannot parse it as an `OrderedDictionary`

```
"OrderedDict([('key1', u'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'))])\n"
```

How can I import it as an `OrderedDict`

`ast.literal_eval(row)` did not work !

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` did not work because it evaluates literals, and `OrderedDict(...)` is not a literal. As a side note, if you're in control of the file format, you should use a different representation.

Comment: Can you change the format of your file to just be tuple pairs? `[('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]`

Comment: Chad, i created the object myself in an streaming fashion and used Orderedict to preserve the ordering of keys ... ideally i wanted to create a json line by line with each line being a pure dictionary, but i was not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a regular expression for safer evaluation:

```
import re
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict

def read(f):
    for s in f:
        m = re.match(r'^OrderedDict\((.+)\)$', s)
        if m:
            yield OrderedDict(ast.literal_eval(m.group(1)))

...
for d in read(snap_fh):
    print type(d)
```

Comment: +1 As I was just about to post something similar but yours is more elegant and clean, with `ast.literal_eval` is way more safer...

Answer (score 4):

Using eval seems to work nicely

```
s = "OrderedDict([('key1', u'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')])"
a = eval(s, {'OrderedDict': OrderedDict})
print (a)
```

Use it **only if you trust** the source of your inputs - since eval is *very risky*

Comment: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @user3100115 - Indeed, but if your trust the input it can be good patch