# Python read ordered dictionary file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an ordered dictionary file. A simple example is one line which is like this:

```
Example.csv
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

I want to read this file and assign it to an ordered dictionary variable in python.

```
file = open("Example.csv", "r")

contents = file.read()
dictionary = ast.literal_eval(contents)

print(dictionary)
file.close()
```

This code works for the above example but raises an error of " malformed node or string:" for the following line:

```
OrderedDict([('kiwi', 4), ('apple', 5), ('cat', 3)])
```

How can I read this line and assign it in a python variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing string as an ordered dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797928/importing-string-as-an-ordered-dictionary)

Comment: `literal_eval` is limited to a rather short list of types: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: oh ok, is there another way to do it? I don't have to use the literal_eval function.

Comment: The `eval` way would work - but it's ugly